# Updating Order to shipped without tracking inventory

Tags: bigcommerce

How can I update an order to shipped that contains an untracked product using the [BigCommerce web API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api)?

I have an order with a product that is [not being tracked as part of the inventory on BigCommerce](https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1541/How+do+I+manage+inventory+with+BigCommerce?).

I need to make an appropriate web API call to update the status to shipped. I have tried to make a call using the [`PUT /orders/id/shipments/id.json`](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/orders/shipments#put-ordersidshipmentsidjson) call like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shipment>
    <tracking_number/>
    <order_address_id>533</order_address_id>
    <items>
        <item>
            <order_product_id>628</order_product_id>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
        </item>
    </items>
</shipment>
```

, but I get the following 400 Bad Request response.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<errors>
    <error>
        <status>400</status>
        <message>The field 'quantity' is invalid.</message>
        <details>
            <invalid_reason>The quantity specified is greater than the quantity of the product that is available to ship.</invalid_reason>
            <available_quantity>0</available_quantity>
            <order_product_id>628</order_product_id>
        </details>
    </error>
</errors>
```

I realize that I could change the product to be tracked, but the customer doesn't track their inventory this way (and I would like to avoid forcing them to change their process). I have tried omitting the quantity, but it states that it is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the orderstatus to shipped. GET request on this endpoint tells you the ids associated with various aspect of an order
http://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/order_statuses

The PUT resource on the order lets you update the status 
http://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/orders

Comment: Your answer is correct, but my real issue was that I was posting a shipment that already exists. It is misleading and I added the following question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17886266/299327