# Clearer response from BigCommerce

Tags: api, httpresponse, api-design, bigcommerce

Can BigCommerce change their API response to be more clear when a program tries to post a shipment that already exists?

When posting shipments to BigCommerce, if the shipment already exists, then you receive the following error message.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<errors>
    <error>
        <status>400</status>
        <message>The field 'quantity' is invalid.</message>
        <details>
            <invalid_reason>The quantity specified is greater than the quantity of the product that is available to ship.</invalid_reason>
            <available_quantity>0</available_quantity>
            <order_product_id>628</order_product_id>
        </details>
    </error>
</errors>
```

I agree that it is a bad request, but it has nothing to do with the quantity of the item. Can we do something like the following for the `message` or `invalid_reason` instead?

```
The shipment [insert ID here] already exists and cannot be added.
```

This would make for a much more usable API.

Comment: I was kicking myself trying to figure out what the heck was going on. This is a silly message for them to throw in this case. I guess the best way to check if it's already ship confirmed is to list the order's shipments first (or after catching an error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When querying the order products resource there is an available quantity to ship, and as you create a shipment(s) the available quantity is reduced to 0.

Initially a shipment POST is successful as the quantity specified in the payload matches that of the order.  If you were to POST a shipment to an order that has already been shipped then the available quantity is actually 0, and when you specify a positive integer for quantity in the payload it is invalid and greater than the available quantity, so the error is accurate.

Comment: It would be great if that were documented somewhere and the error message didn't imply the overall quantity of the item were zero. It is still a very misleading error. How about, "The quantity specified is greater than the quantity of the product that is requested for this order"